# 400 Response code in root url in azure web app biting back

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I've a website with one default route, say `index`. The default root has a validation that if certain query strings are not passed with it, it should return `400 - Bad request`. The web app is hosted in azure with `AlwaysOn` turned off. Now the problem is the `AppInsight` that is configured for this web app logs around 600 `400` response code in every hour. The web app is behind `ApplicationGateway` and traffic manager. Some sample urls are :

https://abcmodule.xyz.com/ - (`400 - Bad Request`)

https://abcmodule.xyz.com/?index=1 (`200 - OK`)

I am unable to figure out what exactly making those `/` requests. When I see the trace of the request I see there is mention of `Initial Event` which makes that request to root url. Any idea how can I get more details on this request like which component exactly calls it?

Comment: Could you explain `The default root has a validation that if certain query strings are not passed with it` to me?

Comment: @JoeyCai - It means there is one controller and one action method in code(asp.net mvc) and that is the default route in our application. But we want to make sure this action method can only be called when there is a query string "index" exist in url, else return 400.